# Return array of text ranges given regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like a function to return an array of start and end ranges given a string and a regular expression. I would like it to behave something like the below:

```
var sometext = "abc1 abc2 abc3 abc2";
var re = /abc2/;

var range_array = match_range(sometext, re)

[[5,8],[15,18]]
```

I imagine there is an elegant function to do this, but a solution escapes me.

**Edit:** I put improper desired ranges in my original example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all the matches and use [`RegExp.lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) to find where the expression engine is after the match has been found:

```
var re = /abc2/g;
//             ^ That's important
var matches = [];

while ((m = re.exec(sometext)) !== null) {
  matches.push([re.lastIndex - m[0].length, re.lastIndex - 1]);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/nowuwexeti/1/)

or as a function:

```
function match_ranges(sometext, re) {
    var matches = [];
    while ((m = re.exec(sometext)) !== null) {
      matches.push([re.lastIndex - m[0].length, re.lastIndex - 1]);
    }
    return matches;
};
```